# Is CLEFIA block cipher really lightweight?

Tags: block-cipher, standards, lightweight

CLEFIA is **ISO/IEC 29192-2** standard in lightweight cryptography. According to [this](http://www.cryptrec.go.jp/report/cryptrec-gl-0001-2016-e.pdf), the total GE area (I took the minimum) using .13 um is 2,488 (encryption mode) compared to piccolo-128 with GE area of 1,776  (encryption mode) and others lightweight block ciphers  . ([reference](http://www.cryptrec.go.jp/report/cryptrec-gl-0001-2016-e.pdf)).

On the software side, CLEFIA consumes large memory (2 8-bits boxes and 2 MDS matrix), it cannot be implemented using 512 bytes (ROM) or 64 bytes (RAM). It  is implemented minimally with a ROM size of 800 bytes compared to Present (164 bytes) LED(298 bytes), Prince (424 bytes), Piccolo (275 bytes) , TWINE(232 bytes)  and others such as  SIMON and SPECK .([reference](http://www.cryptrec.go.jp/report/cryptrec-gl-0001-2016-e.pdf))

In term of performance, figure 1 shows the speed of ciphers with 1024-byte ROM and 128-byte RAM, I see that piccolo lower number of cycles/block compared to CLEFIA in addition , this reference shows that Piccolo-128 with Encryption has GE area of 1776 produces throughput of 193.9 Kbps (@100kHz) compared to CLEFIA-128 has GE area of 2488 produces throughput of 39 9 Kbps (@100kHz). Piccolo looks has better advantages. ([reference](http://www.cryptrec.go.jp/report/cryptrec-gl-0001-2016-e.pdf))

[image: Figure 1 the speed of ciphers with 1024-byte ROM and 128-byte RAM]
In term of security , CLEFIA uses  128, 192 ,256 bit keys compared to the rest lightweight block ciphers which they use 64 and 128 bit keys.

Another point is during my literature, I do not see CLEFIA is included in comparisons with other lightweight ciphers ([Triathlon of Lightweight Block Ciphers for the Internet of Things](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/events/lightweight-cryptography-workshop-2015/documents/papers/session7-grobschadl-paper.pdf)). This triggered my question: **How did CLEFIA got standardized as lightweight block-cipher?**

Comment: You've given excellent reasons why CLEFIA may not be a good candidate for a lightweight block cipher. But unless there are any formal rules for classifying ciphers I think the final classification of CLEFIA is based upon opinion rather than reasoning.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That might as well be an answer, given that there basically is no objective incontestable way to say it is/is not lightweight

Comment: Related: [What is the official, generally accepted definition of “lightweight crypto”?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/45129/12164)